# Multiplying Custom Units

Tags: java, class, oop, object

For what I'm doing I am creating a program to multiply and divide measurements. Currently I'm stuck on the multiplication. I have created a class called Measurement that takes a value and a unit so a typical constructor is:

> Measurement x = new Measurement(5, "in^2");

Currently my output is:

> Mult: 5.0 in * 3.0 in = 15.0 in^2
>
> Mult: 5.0 in * 3.0 lb = 15.0 in*lb
>
> Mult: 4.0 in^5 * 3.0 in^3 = 12.0 in^5*in^3

As you can see, the first three outputs are fine, but whenever I get over an exponent of 4, it cant multiply the two exponents. I also cannot figure out multiplying something along the lines of:

> Mult: 5.0 in^2/lb * 3.0 lb = 15 in^2

Here is how I've currently set it up:

```
public Measurement mult(Measurement measure){
        String newUnit="";
        String inUnit = measure.getUnit();
        double script = 1;
        double newVal = 0;
        newVal = measure.getVal()*val;
        if(inUnit.indexOf(un) > -1){
            if(un.charAt(un.length()-1) == inUnit.charAt(inUnit.length()-1))
                newUnit = un+"^2";
            else{
                if (inUnit.contains("^")){
                    int i = inUnit.indexOf("^")+1;
                    script += Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(inUnit.charAt(i)));
                }
                if(un.contains("^")){
                    int j = inUnit.indexOf("^")+1;

                    script += Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(un.charAt(j)));
                }
                else
                    script+=0;
                System.out.println(script);
                newUnit = un+"^"+ Integer.toString((int)script);
            }
        }
       else if(inUnit.indexOf(un) == -1)
            newUnit = un+"*"+inUnit;

        Measurement out = new Measurement(newVal, newUnit);
        return out;
```

}

Comment: Maybe, and ONLY MAYBE, Polish reverse notation.

Comment: An [MCVE] could help. Until then, just a hint: The JScience library already went the extra mile here: http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/package-summary.html

Comment: @Marco13 I would use that, but this is more of me learning from a more barebones perspective and to prepare myself for a course I am taking next semester. This is an old project from about 9 years ago that the professor told me to look at to prepare if I wanted.

Comment: You can go arbitrarily far here. For example, should it be possible to convert a unit like `in*in/(lb*in)^2` into its "most simple form"? Then you'd basically have to *model* the units as classes, probably as some sort of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree , and apply a simplification...